# Connect multiple sound card inputs using the Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, audio-recording, web-audio-api

Is it possible to connect several sound card inputs using the Web Audio API?

I have an 8-channel-input sound card and want to connect each of them to an audio node, so I can modulate, filter, and mix them all together to one stereo output, just like other digital audio workstation software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we've wired this up on the input side yet in Chrome.  The output side works, however.